# one liner for editing the second last line of a file, using awk or sed?

Tags: sed, awk

Original File:

```
{ 

A:2, 

B:2, 

C:2, 

}
```

Required:

```
{

A:2,

B:2, 

C:2 

}
```

Is there a way to do this using awk or sed in one line?

Comment: Is it me, or are the two files exactly the same minus the removed comma?

Comment: Asking for a solution "in one line" is a goofy request. A "line" can be a thousand characters long - what's the point?

Comment: They are the same, other than the comma. I have edit the 2nd last line in the file (remove comma). The line can be of variable length.

Comment: @EdMorton: I was trying to ask if there is a typical Sed, awk one liner to do this.

Comment: Any awk and most sed scripts can be written on one line, it's just often not a desirable layout for the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU awk:

```
$ cat file
{

A:2,

B:2,

C:2,

}

$ gawk -v RS='\0' -v ORS= '{print gensub(/,([^,]+)$/,"\\1","")}' file
{

A:2,

B:2,

C:2

}
```

If you ever need to do this on files containing multiple blocks like the above, change the script from:

```
gawk -v RS='\0' -v ORS= '{print gensub(/,([^,]+)$/,"\\1","")}' file
```

to:

```
gawk -v RS='\0' -v ORS= '{print gensub(/,([^,]+})/,"\\1","g")}' file
```

e.g.:

```
$ cat file
{

A:2,

B:2,

C:2,

}

{

D:2,

E:2,

F:2,

}
$
$ gawk -v RS='\0' -v ORS= '{print gensub(/,([^,]+})/,"\\1","g")}' file
{

A:2,

B:2,

C:2

}

{

D:2,

E:2,

F:2

}
```

Comment: If you're happy with this solution, remember to click on the check mark next to it so others won't waste their time posting alternatives trying to help you find a solution.